# Embedded PowerBI in SharePoint - Targeted Audience?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, target-audience

I have a number of PowerBI dashboards on our SharePoint 2013 online site.  We are working on a plan to only display relevant dashboards to the user based on their user group.  For example, a salesperson will only see their personal dashboard on the page.  I can do this for image viewer, etc., but I cannot figure out how to edit a PowerBI webpart to target an audience.  Any suggestions would be most welcomed.

KL

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Row level security.

1. Select the Modeling tab.
2. Select Manage Roles.

[image]

3.Select Create

[image]

4.Provide a name for the role.

5.Select the table that you want to apply a DAX rule.

6.Enter the DAX expressions. This expression should return a true or false. For example: [UserID] = userprincipalname().

7. And Save.

For this you need a field where the username is registered, means that user has visibility on that row. If you don't have this information, then you will need to add some information to the row, to give visibility to whom deserve it.

After you have created your role, you can test the results of the role within Power BI Desktop. To do this, select View As Roles.

[image]

And then play around to check if what you get is what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there any way to do this using targeted audience in SP?  I need to have a single page that displays the content for that audience.  All of the dashboards would be on the content page, but the user would only see those he/she is targeted for.  This can be done with images, page viewer, etc.  I was hoping to do the same for the Power BI content.

Comment: Well somehow you need a filter giving a role. Then you can assign people or group of people to this role, so when they access to the power bi report, they will see only their data.

Comment: Nelson, I understand, but I have to work this out with SP and not using the permissions in BI.  Seems like I may not have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I had to revert the SP page to a Classic interface, then create individual Web Parts for each dashboard on the page, limiting each Web Part by the targeted audience.  The Web Parts are not visible on the main Dashboard Portal page unless you are in the targeted audience, so you could see 1 or up to 5 dashboard previews on the page.  An individual page was needed for each Power BI dashboard.  A user cannot be prevented from seeing the dashboard if they are provided the URL, but hiding the hyperlink and preview screenshot on the Portal page is close enough.  This should be easier to execute in SP...  Oh well...